# How to aggregate Unit testing and Integration test coverage result

Tags: gitlab-ci, code-coverage, jacoco, test-coverage

```
gradle-check:
  ...
  script:
    - ./gradlew check --console=plain ${GRADLE_CHECK_OPTS}
  after_script:
    - mkdir build/reports/tests/ut/
    - mv build/reports/tests/test/* build/reports/tests/ut/
  artifacts:
    when: always
    expire_in: 1 week
    reports:
      junit: build/test-results/test/**/TEST-*.xml
    paths:
      - build/reports/jacocoHtml/
      - build/reports/tests/ut/

integration-test:
  ...
  script:
    - ./gradlew test -Dtest.profile=integration --tests "com.test.integrationtest.*"
    - cat build/reports/jacocoHtml/index.html
  coverage: '/Total.*?([0-9]{1,3})%/'
  after_script:
    - mkdir build/reports/tests/it/
    - mv build/reports/tests/test/* build/reports/tests/it/
  artifacts:
    when: always
    expire_in: 1 week
    reports:
      junit: build/test-results/test/**/TEST-*.xml
    paths:
      - build/reports/jacocoHtml/
      - build/reports/tests/it/

pages:
  stage: pages
  dependencies:
    - gradle-check
    - integration-test
  script:
    - mkdir -p public
    - mv build/reports/tests/ut/ public/
    - mv build/reports/tests/it/ public/
    - mv build/reports/jacocoHtml/ public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
    expire_in: 100 yrs
  when: always
  ....
```

I wanted aggregation between Unit Testing & Integration Testing coverage,
I can see only unit testing coverage is generated in gitlab pipeline,
And integration test coverage is not getting generated in pipeline.

gradle.build file below

```
def jacocoTestExclude = [
        'com/test/constants/**',
        'com/test/model/**',
]
jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.enabled true
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/reports/jacocoHtml")
    }
    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: jacocoTestExclude
            )
        }))
    }
}

jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                minimum = 0.0
            }

            failOnViolation true
        }
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: 'jacocoExclude'
            )
        }))
    }
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.7"
}

test {
    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams = true
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
    }
    if (System.properties['test.profile'] != 'integration') {
        exclude '**/*integrationtest*'
    }
}

check.dependsOn jacocoTestCoverageVerification
jacocoTestCoverageVerification.dependsOn jacocoTestReport
```

Since integration test class is not required to run with unit test I have excluded that in test().
jacocoTestCoverageVerification doesn't have any exclusion, some dummy string it is